# Showing comment form on each post, throws "undefined method `comments' for 1:Integer" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User via devise, Book, Post, and Comment. When I go to show.html.erb for Book, I can post. These posts are listed on the same url, show.html.erb for Book. Attached to each of these posts is a comment form. Comment, once posted, would be listed on the same url, beneath that particular post.

My problem is that after adding code for comment, show.html.erb for Book no longer shows. It throws an error: "undefined method `comments' for 1:Integer". The comment form "form_for([post, post.id.comments.build])" is highlighted. I have scoured here and elsewhere and the api for answers to no avail.

My code:

book controller (in the comments are a score of code I've tried):

```rb
...
    def show

        # @user = current_user
        # @book = @user.books.find(params[:id])
        # @post = @book.posts.find(params[:id])
        # @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

        # @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        # @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        # @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

        # @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        # @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        # @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        @post = @book.posts.new

        # @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
        # @comment = @posts.comments.new
        # @comment = Comment.new


        # @post = @book.posts.find(params[:id])
        # @comment = Comment.new

    end
```

Specifying Post.find(params[:id]) throws "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=27" error. 27 is the id of the Book. Uncommenting the first four lines throws "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=27 [WHERE "posts"."book_id" = $1]" error.

comments controller (posts controller, I think, is okay but please let me know if you want it):

```rb
    def index
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @posts = Post.all 
        @comments = @post.comments.all
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        render :template => 'books/show'
    end

    def new
        # @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        # @comment = @post.comments.new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new
        render :template => 'books/show'
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(:id)
        render :template => 'books/show'
    end

    def create
        # @user = current_user
        # @book = @user.books.find(params[:book_id])
        # @post = @book.posts.find(params[:post_id])
        # @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params) { user: current_user}

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to book_path(@book), notice: "Success!~"
        else 
            redirect_to book_path(@book), alert: "Failure!" 
        end

    end

    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
        end
```

show.html.erb for Book:

```
<%= form_for([@book, @book.posts.build]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<% @book.posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>
    <%= @book.title %>
    <%= post.text %>
  </p>
  <%= form_for([post, post.id.comments.build]) do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.text_area :text %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've tried @post, @post.comments.build, as well as without @, both of which throw this error: "No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:post_id]"

routes for the nested resources:

```rb
  resources :users do
    resources :books, shallow: true do
      resources :posts, shallow: true do
        resources :comments, shallow: true 
      end
    end
  end
```

The schema seems fine, with user_id and post_id in comments.

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Which line in your code is giving this error?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar I'm sorry, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<%= form_for(post.comments.build, url: "/posts/#{post.id}/comments")  do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thank you for this. Getting "undefined method `model_name' for {:url=>"/posts/1/comments"}:Hash." Could the clue be in the way I nested the routes?

Comment: Maybe you can try this: <%= form_for post.comments.build, url: "/posts/#{post.id}/comments" do |form| %>. It's just without the parentheses.

Comment: After I got rid of [] it seems to work -- the page is showing with the comment form. I also got rid of the deep nested resources. Thank you! (now having trouble creating comment; will work on it and create a new question later if I can't solve it. But if you see something wrong here, please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is `no record found` for the `book` with `params[:id]` so it cannot call the `posts of that book` and in turn, the `post` cannot have `comments` so,

You should specify something like this.

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@post = @book.posts.find(params[:post_id]) if @book.present?
@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]) if @post.present?
```

For further reference, you can look into [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: Thank you. It throws this error: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=27 [WHERE "posts"."book_id" = $1]

Comment: I don't see any routes and relationship regarading goal. could you post in more detail

Comment: Sorry, the comment edited; I was typing and mistyped

Comment: Thank you for this. Throws this error: ...books_controller.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @post = @book.posts.find(params[:p... ^~~~~ ...: syntax error, unexpected if (modifier), expecting ')' ...st.comments.find(params[:id] if @post.present? ... ^~

Comment: Thank you again. The database shows all the books (which is how I accessed show.html.erb for book) and posts as well, with book_id. Posts also show on show.html.erb for book. It is the comment form that's not working.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it and didn't work (details in the question).